# JAVA Discord Bot (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I have a weird problem. Since I'm new in coding, maybe I am dumb and I don't know how can I resolve this issue, so the issue is, I have 2 commands for my discord bot, permanent mute, and temporary mute. I want to make something like a placeholder to be used in config.yml since it will be more configurable, but when I use args[], I have a weird problem, here is it :

```
    [JDA MainWS-ReadThread] ERROR net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA - One of the EventListeners had an uncaught exception
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
        at me.trashlord.bot.events.TempMuteCommand.onGuildMessageReceived(TempMuteCommand.java:34)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter.onEvent(ListenerAdapter.java:396)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.InterfacedEventManager.handle(InterfacedEventManager.java:96)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handleInternally(EventManagerProxy.java:82)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handle(EventManagerProxy.java:69)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.JDAImpl.handleEvent(JDAImpl.java:166)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.MessageCreateHandler.handleInternally(MessageCreateHandler.java:97)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:36)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onDispatch(WebSocketClient.java:921)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onEvent(WebSocketClient.java:808)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.handleEvent(WebSocketClient.java:786)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onBinaryMessage(WebSocketClient.java:959)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnBinaryMessage(ListenerManager.java:385)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnBinaryMessage(ReadingThread.java:276)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleBinaryFrame(ReadingThread.java:996)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:755)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:108)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.runMain(ReadingThread.java:64)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketThread.run(WebSocketThread.java:45)
```

ALSO, here is my code at those lines :

```
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");

        String MutedMessage = ConfigManager.INSTANCE.getSetting("MutedMessage")
                .replaceAll("%muteduser", args[1]);

        String UnMutedMessage = ConfigManager.INSTANCE.getSetting("UnMutedMessage")
                .replaceAll("%unmuteduser", args[1]);

        String TempMuted1 = ConfigManager.INSTANCE.getSetting("TempMutedMSG")
                .replaceAll("%tempmutedusr", String.valueOf(event.getGuild().getMemberById(args[1].replaceAll("[^\\d]+", ""))))
                .replaceAll("%tempmutetime", args[2]);

        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Commands.prefix + "mute")) {
            if (Objects.requireNonNull(event.getMember()).hasPermission(Permission.MESSAGE_MANAGE)) {
                if (args.length == 2) {
                    Member member = event.getGuild().getMemberById(args[1].replaceAll("[^\\d]+", ""));
                    Role role = event.getGuild().getRoleById(MutedRole);

                    if (!Objects.requireNonNull(member).getRoles().contains(role)) {
                        // Mute user
                        event.getChannel().sendMessage(MutedMessage).queue();
                        event.getGuild().addRoleToMember(member, Objects.requireNonNull(role)).complete();
                    } else {
                        // Unmute user
                        event.getChannel().sendMessage(UnMutedMessage).queue();
                        event.getGuild().removeRoleFromMember(member, Objects.requireNonNull(role)).complete();
                    }
                } else if (args.length == 3) {
                    Member member = event.getGuild().getMemberById(args[1].replaceAll("[^\\d]+", ""));
                    Role role = event.getGuild().getRoleById(MutedRole);

                    //event.getChannel().sendMessage(TempMuted1 + " " + args[1] + " " + TempMuted2 + " " + args[2] + " " + TempMuted3).queue();
                    event.getChannel().sendMessage(TempMuted1).queue();
                    event.getGuild().addRoleToMember(Objects.requireNonNull(member), Objects.requireNonNull(role))
                            .complete();

                    // Unmute after a few seconds
                    new java.util.Timer().schedule(
                            new java.util.TimerTask() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    event.getChannel().sendMessage(TempUnMuted + " " + args[1] + ".").queue();
                                    event.getGuild().removeRoleFromMember(member, role).complete();
                                }
                            },
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(Integer.parseInt(args[2]))
                    );
                } else {
                    event.getChannel().sendMessage("Incorrect syntax. Use `~mute [user mention] [time {optional}]`")
                            .queue();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is you are trying to get an element from args[2], which may the array only contains 2 elements (length 2) in the following code:

```
String TempMuted1 = ConfigManager.INSTANCE.getSetting("TempMutedMSG")
        .replaceAll("%tempmutedusr", String.valueOf(event.getGuild().getMemberById(args[1].replaceAll("[^\\d]+", ""))))
        .replaceAll("%tempmutetime", args[2]);
```

Note that in java arrays are zero-based and indexes start from 0 to length - 1.
You can take this code inside the if-condition:

```
else if (args.length == 3) {
     String TempMuted1 = ConfigManager.INSTANCE.getSetting("TempMutedMSG")
            .replaceAll("%tempmutedusr", String.valueOf(event.getGuild().getMemberById(args[1].replaceAll("[^\\d]+", ""))))
            .replaceAll("%tempmutetime", args[2]);
// your code
}
```

Comment: Ahh, now I understand it. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this line from your code:

```
String TempMuted1 = ConfigManager.INSTANCE.getSetting("TempMutedMSG")
            .replaceAll("%tempmutedusr", String.valueOf(event.getGuild().getMemberById(args[1].replaceAll("[^\\d]+", ""))))
            .replaceAll("%tempmutetime", args[2]);
```

args[1] and args[2] is correct?

If the length is 2, Then args[2] is looking for the 3rd value and you might not have it...
Have a further look on how length and index works for arrays.